# Form To Wizard and Zurb Foundation Abide Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, zurb-foundation

I am using [Form To Wizard](http://www.ifadey.com/2012/06/form-to-wizard-jquery-plugin/) to create a multi page form (each fieldset is a separate page). I'm also using [Foundation Abide Validation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html) to validate my forms, however I am having trouble getting the two to work together.

The formToWizard has a "validateBeforeNext" function that I should be able to use to trigger Abide Validation, but how do I get Abide to only validate the current fieldset and not let the user progress until the current page is correctly filled out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles on this and has the same issue, I finally figured it out.

You need to use the Foundation.libs.abide.parse_patterns() function and pass through a list of all of the elements that you want validated. So basically your formToWizard call looks like this:

```
    $("#signup_form").formToWizard({ 
        submitButton: 'SaveAccount',
        showProgress: true,
        showStepNo: false,
        validateBeforeNext: function() {
            return Foundation.libs.abide.parse_patterns($('.signup_form_fieldset:visible').find(':input[required]'))[0];                   
        }
    });
```